# Pixela graph not reciving parameters given

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

```
import requests

USERNAME="username"
TOKEN="token"
pixela_endpoint = ("https://pixe.la/v1/users")
params={
    "token":TOKEN,
    "username": USERNAME,
    "agreeTermsOfService": "yes",
    "notMinor": "yes",
}
graph_endpoint=f"{pixela_endpoint}/{USERNAME}/graphs"
graph_params={
    "id": "graph1",
    "name": "Working Graph",
    "unit": "H",
    "type": "float",
    "color ": "momiji"
}
headers={
    "X-USER-TOKEN": TOKEN
}
response_graph=requests.post(url=graph_endpoint,json=graph_params,headers=headers)
print(response_graph.text)
```

I get this message (second part seems to be the problem):

```
{"message":"It is necessary to specify id, name, unit, type, and color params.","isSuccess":false}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you gave wrong value to your keys in graph parameters. Also endpoint might be wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).